# Flutter streambuilder not updating UI when listening to changes in a single firestore document

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-streambuilder

I have a screen that listens for changes in a document using a stream builder. If the document has data then it shows `Widget1`, otherwise it will show `Widget2`.

**The problem:**
When the stream builder builds for the first time it uses `Widget2` since there is no data, but when it receives the data it does not update the widget to `Widget2`.

**Here is my simplified implementation:**

```
class Test extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
  const Test({ Key? key }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  ConsumerState<Test> createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends ConsumerState<Test> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // final match = ref.watch(matchedEventProvider);
    final user = ref.read(currentUserProvider);

    return Scaffold(
      body:StreamBuilder<Object>(
        stream: db
            .collection(kMatchedCollection)
            .doc(user.currentMatch)
            .snapshots(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.data != null) {
            kLogger.d('snapshot data: ${snapshot.data.toString()}');
            final snap =
                snapshot.hasData ? snapshot.data as DocumentSnapshot : null;
            matchData = snap?.data() as Map<String, dynamic>;

            kLogger.d("Got real match data: $matchData");
            matchData['CreatedAt'] = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(
                    matchData['CreatedAt'].seconds * 1000)
                .toString();
            final Event event = Event.fromJson(matchData);
            final String status = event.EventStatus;
            if (event.AssignedTo == ref.read(currentUserProvider).id) {
              //only push new screens if current user is assigned.
              if (status == Status.dateCancelled) {
                Navigator.pop(context);
              } else if (status == Status.dateConfirmed) {
                Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(
                    context, FinalConfirmationScreen.id);
              } else if (status == Status.deciding) {
                Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(
                    context, FinalConfirmationScreen.id);
              }
            }

            return Widget1();
          } else {
            kLogger.d("has data ${snapshot.hasData}");
            return Widget2();
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

**Here are the corresponding logs:**

```
/flutter (  988): ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter (  988): │ #0   _LocationWaitScreenState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:app/screens/location_wait_screen.dart:154:21)
I/flutter (  988): │ #1   StreamBuilder.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:437:81)
I/flutter (  988): ├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
I/flutter (  988): │  has data false
I/flutter (  988): └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter (  988): ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter (  988): │ #0   _LocationWaitScreenState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:app/screens/location_wait_screen.dart:44:21)
I/flutter (  988): │ #1   StreamBuilder.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:437:81)
I/flutter (  988): ├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
I/flutter (  988): │  snapshot data: Instance of '_JsonDocumentSnapshot'
I/flutter (  988): └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter (  988): ┌───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
I/flutter (  988): │ #0   _LocationWaitScreenState.build.<anonymous closure> (package:app/screens/location_wait_screen.dart:49:21)
I/flutter (  988): │ #1   StreamBuilder.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/async.dart:437:81)
I/flutter (  988): ├┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄┄
I/flutter (  988): │  Got real match data: {StartedWith: bCO38DzmjrU9DsT4FTvU7uqR4r42, AssignedTo: bCO38DzmjrU9DsT4FTvU7uqR4r42, DocID: a1776e3d180543b084, Resets: 3, CreatedAt: Timestamp(seconds=1703706807, nanoseconds=365138000), EventStatus: Start, Time: , Participants: [RaLpzb2BZBUnn8AYYJ5UiApmmtx2, bCO38DzmjrU9DsT4FTvU7uqR4r42], Location: }
I/flutter (  988): └───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
```

From the logs we can observe that it first builds `Widget2` as it says  `has data false` and then when the snapshot receives data it tries to build `Widget1` but these **build changes are not reflected in the UI**.

Any help on this would be appreciated

Comment: have you tried using the initialData parameter on your streamBuilder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To all the new people stumbling on this question, the problem is with an animation library that I was using. Don't try to modify the Text Widget child inside the animation widget and instead only use one animation widget while conditionally rendering.

So the code will go from this:

```
 if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return const Animation(child: Text('Widget 1'));
          } else {
            return const Animation(child: Text('Widget 2'));
          }
        },
```

to :

```
 if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return const Animation(child: Text('Widget 1'));
          } else {
            return Text('Widget 2');
          }
        },
```

Removing the `Animation`widget while rendering conditionally fixed this issue for me.

Note: Here `Animation` widget could be any generic animation library widget from pub.dev .

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking if snapshot.data is null. Consider using the function hasData i.e

```
StreamBuilder<Object>(
  stream: <DB stream>,
  builder: (context, snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
    // your logic here
      
      return Widget1();
    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
      // Handle error state if needed
      return ErrorWidget();
    } else {
      kLogger.d("has data ${snapshot.hasData}");
      return Widget2();
    }
  },
)
```

Here is a simple example  to simulate a stream please try it out and update your code accordingly if it works. If it works it means something is wrong with your ConsumerStateful widget and ConsumerState

```
void main() => runApp(const MyApp()); //app entry point

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Simulate Stream',
      theme: ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.dark,
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const Test(), //load home widget
    );
  }
}

class Test extends StatefulWidget {
  const Test({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Test> createState() => _TestState();
}

class _TestState extends State<Test> {
  final StreamController<String> _streamController = StreamController<String>();

  void simulateStream() {
    _streamController.add('Data 1');
    // You can add more data as needed
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      floatingActionButton: ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: simulateStream, child: const Text('Add data')),
      body: StreamBuilder<Object>(
        stream: _streamController.stream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            return const Center(child: Text('Widget 1'));
          } else {
            return const Center(child: Text('Widget 2'));
          }
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the feedback but it does not solve the widget rebuilding issue.

Comment: @Pratyush there might something wrong with your ConsumerStatefulWidget and ConsumerState widgets i have updated the answer with a simple implementation to simulate the stream please try it out and update your code accordingly if it works

Comment: Thank you, but apparently the issue was with an animation library that Widget1 and Widget2 were both using.  I configured the program to only use animation in Widget1 and it worked. Will update the question and the answer soon.